Get data concerning sound level from react-audio-visualize
I am using react-webcam library to record audio/video from webcam. However, I would like to have some visualisation of recorded audio. I use react-audio-visualize library and pass my mediaRecorder ref to it. Visualisation is displayed. Apart from that I would like to have display some notification if sound level is too low. Obviously, react-audio-visualize calculates such data for visualisation purposes. For sure it does some fft. I would like to somehow access this data. How could I do that? Documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-audio-visualize does not mention that, but probably it is possible, but I do not know how to do that.
